# Why isn't onServiceConnected called?

Tags: android

I am a beginner who made a simple program to show how services work.

```
.....
toStartService = new Intent(this, SimpleService.class);
    sc = new ServiceConnection() {            
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Toast.makeText(MoreService.this, "SC: Binded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Toast.makeText(MoreService.this, "SC: Unbinded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }    
    };


    startService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MoreService.this, "Starting Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startService(toStartService);        
        }
    });

    stopService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(toStartService);
        }
    });

    bindService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if((isBound = bindService(toStartService, sc, BIND_AUTO_CREATE))) {

            }
        }
    });

    unbindService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isBound) {
                unbindService(sc);
                isBound = false;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Why didn't passing the sc variable (on bindService()) call the sc.onServiceConnected() method?
Whats wrong with the code?

I met this following condition:

- When i press [startService] the
  service started well, then
  [stopService] the service stoped well.
- When i press [startService] then the [bindService] does nothing, neither the [unbindService].
- When i press [bindService], its created the service, the [stopService] didnt work.  I press [unbindService] the service is calling the onDestroy() method.

Why does the service that is created by bindService is destroyed when unbinded? I try to start the service with startService, but it cannot bind.

Arrgh help mee, sorry if i was wrong.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Now I see why a lot of people hate Java... 
Anyway be very careful when you say "what's wrong with the code" because there are millions of pretending "attitude police" on this website that do nothing but going around voting down questions like yours.

Answer (score 2):

This is the designed behavior of all of these methods.  For example, in the `bindService(Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags)` method according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29), the service will only run as long as the calling context exists:

> The service will be considered required by the system only for as long as the calling context exists. For example, if this Context is an Activity that is stopped, the service will not be required to continue running until the Activity is resumed.

For [`unbindService (ServiceConnection conn)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService%28android.content.ServiceConnection%29) the documentation says:

> Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is now allowed to stop at any time.

In the [`startService (Intent service)` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) it says:

> Using `startService()` overrides the default service lifetime that is managed by `bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)`: it requires the service to remain running until `stopService(Intent)` is called, regardless of whether any clients are connected to it. Note that calls to `startService()` are not nesting: no matter how many times you call `startService()`, a single call to `stopService(Intent)` will stop it.

Comment: thanks, "the service will only run as long as the calling context exists", then how do i bind to a service that is already running?

Comment: If the service is started by `startService`, then you can bind to it and it will remain running after you unbind, but if it was started by `bindService`, then it will remain running only as long as the calling context exists.

Comment: Oh i just insert mBinder in the onBind method of the service, and then the ServiceConnection is working now! Why it can be like this?